# Limit the js window scroll variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to limit the `wScroll` variable between 0 and 90 so the code won’t bug?

```
$(function(){

  $(window).on({
    scroll: function() {
      let wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      
      $("img").css({
        "transform":"rotateZ(" + wScroll + "deg)"
      })
    }
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `Math.max`? `let wScroll = Math.max($(this).scrollTop(), 90)`

Comment: @putvande nah, doesn’t really work ;/

Comment: Oh, sorry, that needs to be `Math.min($(this).scrollTop(), 90)`.

Comment: @putvande thanks a lot, working perfectly!